# Search a relation without a second query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, ruby-on-rails-3

My question is about how to perform varying levels of search into a database while limiting the number of queries.

Let's start simple:

```
@companies = Company.where("active = ?", true)
```

Let's say we display records from this set. Then, we need:

```
@clientcompanies = @companies.where("client_id = ?", @client.id)
```

We display something from @clientcompanies. Then, we want to drill down further.

```
@searchcompanies = @clientcompanies.where("name LIKE ? OR notes LIKE ?", "#{params[:search]}%", "#{params[:search]}%")
```

Are these three statements the most efficient way to go about this?

If indeed the database is starting with the entire Company table each time around, is there a way to limit the scope so each of the above statements would take a shorter amount of time as the size of the set diminishes?

In case it matters, I'm running Rails 3 on both MySQL and PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't get much more optimized then what you're already doing.  Exactly zero of those statements will execute a SQL query until you try to iterate over the results.  Calling methods like `all`, `first`, `inspect`, `any?`, `each` etc will be when the query is executed.

Each time you chain on a new `where` or other arel method, it appends to the sql query that it'll execute at the end.  If, somewhere in the middle, you want to see the query that'll be executed you can do `puts @searchcompanies.to_sql`

Note that if you run these commands in the console each statement appears to run a SQL query only because the console automatically runs `.inspect` on the line you entered.

Hopefully I answered your question :)

There's a great railscast here:  http://railscasts.com/episodes/239-activerecord-relation-walkthrough that explains how ActiveRelation works, and what you can do with it.

EDIT:

I may have mis-understood your question.  You indicated that after each `where` call you were displaying information from the query.  What's the use-case for this?  Are you displaying all companies on the same page that you have filtered-out companies from a search?  If you display something from that very first query then you will be pulling every single company row from your database (which is not going to be very scalable or performant at larger quantities of company entries).

Would it not make sense to only display information from the `@searchcompanies` variable?

Comment: My use case for displaying the data from these various levels of queries is simple - imagine a page which 'drills down' through some data and shows details about each level to the user. Let's say I want to show the user some sample `companies`, then some sample `clientcompanies`, along with the user's actual search. My question hinges on this case where I need to do these queries but I want to do them as lightly as possible.